# VBA - ADODB connect to remote Oracle db

Tags: excel, vba, oracle11g, adodb

I am developing an Excel VBA program that I want to connect to a remote Oracle 11g database, run a query, and return the data to Excel.

Connection strings and drivers are all OK as far as I know. (see below)

It was working perfectly for a while yesterday, connecting to db and returning with correct data. Then I saved and closed the workbook, opened it 20 minutes later (no changes made!) and when I ran the macro I got the following error:

> Runtime error '-2147418113 (8000ffff)': Catastrophic failure

any ideas what could be causing the error?
Could it be something on the DB's side?

Thanks

```
Sub ExtractFromOracle(environment As String)

Dim cn As ADODB.connection
Dim recordSet As ADODB.recordSet
Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set recordSet = CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")

Dim SQLQuery As String
SQLQuery = "SELECT User_Id, Prof_Id FROM user_profile ORDER BY User_Id ASC"

Dim returnData As Variant
Dim returnedRowsCount As Integer

Dim connectionString As String
connectionString = ReturnConnectionString(environment)


cn.Open (connectionString) ------------> ERROR OCCURS HERE


Set recordSet = cn.Execute(SQLQuery)
returnData = Application.Transpose(recordSet.GetRows)
returnedRowsCount = UBound(returnData)

If Not SheetExist(environment) Then
CreateTab (environment)
End If

Worksheets(environment).Activate
ActiveSheet.Range("A1:B" & returnedRowsCount) = returnData

Set rs = Nothing
Set cn = Nothing

ConsolidateUsers (environment)


End Sub
```

CONNECTION STRING :

```
"Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(CID=GTU_APP)(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=xxxxxxx)(PORT=xxxx)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=xxxxx)(SERVER=DEDICATED)));User Id=xxxxxx;Password=xxxxxxx;"
```

Comment: What happens if you remove those lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the error so I though I would update for anyone  with the same issue who finds this thread.

It turns out that the 'Catastrophic Failure' error was due to my Oracle ODBC driver (oraOLEDB.oracle) becoming somehow corrupted, I couldn't even reinstall it properly, the error only occurred on my machine.

In the end I did a system restore to a point from before the issue and all was fixed. Not the most elegant solution but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to access the ADODB as below

```
Dim strSQL  As String, conStr as String
Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset


conStr = "Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(CID=GTU_APP)(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=xxxxxxx)(PORT=xxxx)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=xxxxx)(SERVER=DEDICATED)));User Id=xxxxxx;Password=xxxxxxx;"

Dim SQLQuery As String
SQLQuery = "SELECT User_Id, Prof_Id FROM user_profile ORDER BY User_Id ASC"

cnn.open conStr   
rs.Open SQLQuery, cnn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText
```

Comment: Please put the path where the database is stored in the `conStr` and close the Database and try again. Thanks.

Comment: Please check the modified solution. Thanks

Comment: Thank you. I have tried the modified solution and now it return the previous error again "Runtime error '-2147418113 (8000ffff)': Catastrophic failure" perhaps this is something to do the the DB settings? Should I maybe contact a DBA to restart to DB or otherwise?

Comment: Take the OraClient12 and oraClient11 references (4 in all) out of the Path environment variable and replaced it with a reference to the SysWow64 folder, as a 32bit version of the oraClient11 is stored there. (If this does not help. Then it is out of my range :(

Comment: I will try that and if it works I will report back and let you know. Thank you for you help!!

Comment: Your Welcome. And sorry, if i am not that much of a help